# In distributed mode can locust know if other worker already run task for a particular user

Tags: distributed, locust

community.

I need users created by different workers not to be duplicated. I.e. if **worker_1** create user **fake1** and run task for this user, **worker_2** must not to be able create user **fake1**.

Currently it works only in standalone mode.

```
credentials = [ (f"fake{i}", 'password') for i in range(100) ]

class MobileUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [RealTimeTask]
    wait_time = constant_pacing(1)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        if len(credentials) > 0:
            shuffle(credentials)
            self.username, self.password = credentials.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Slaves are blissfully unaware of each other.

I think your best options is to set an env var at worker start time:

`WORKER_ID=1 locust --worker ...`

(and then insert `os.env['WORKER_ID']` into your user names to make them unique)

Every worker *does* have a unique id (accessible from a task using `self.environment.runner.client_id`), but they are not ordered (they contain hostname + a UUID), so I dont know if that really helps you.

Another option might be to use hostname + process id as an identifier.

Comment: It is a pity. 

I know I can get the worker ID from `environment.runner.client_id`, but I cannot use it in the usernames because the list of usernames is already predefined and I can only use those users.
If I could use a scope common to all the workers being created: in this scope I could store a list of credentials, and during user hatching, I can define username that are not duplicated in different workers.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that it would require worker-worker communication (which doesnt exist) or at least expanding slave-worker communication. See https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1506 for a feature request slightly similar to what you want and a couple of suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: I think, that add worker-worker communication is bad idea. 
But for example, already exists event hook `report_to_master`: "It can be used to attach data to the dicts that are regularly sent to the master. It's fired regularly when a report is to be sent to the master server." 
Maybe can be added event hook that regulary fired when task at worker being started.

Comment: yes, something like that could work. but it does not exist at the moment.